# How can I know if an ELF file is for Cortex-A or Cortex-M?

Tags: arm, executable, elf, cortex-m, cortex-a

I have a question when doing the binary analysis. For a given ELF file (`hello.elf`) that has already been identified for the ARM architecture, **how can I quickly know if this ELF is for Cortex-A or Cortex-M?** More specifically, I'm trying to identify the whole bare-metal images (or RTOS images like FreeRTOS) for the Cortex-M.

From the result of `file hello.elf`:

```sh
% file hello.elf
hello.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped
```

We can only see that this ELF is for ARM.
And from the result of `readelf -h ./hello.elf`:

```
% readelf -h ./hello.elf
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xcb5
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          150896 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000200, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         5
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         19
  Section header string table index: 17
```

It's also only showing this file is for the ARM architecture.
So are there any other approaches that can quickly identify the target architecture of an ELF file?

Comment: What makes you think it has to be for only one or the other?  You can easily tell if it is a whole bare-metal image for Cortex-M by examining the section names present or disassembly with objdump and looking for a vector table, but an executable to run under an OS might be harder to distinguish or even compatible with both.

Comment: @TomV Could you give me some more details about how to do the former one? I'm looking for the whole bare-metal images (or RTOS images like FreeRTOS) for the Cortex-M.

Comment: `arm-none-eabi-objdump -h hello.elf`  Look for a section called `.vectors` or similar.   `arm-none-eabi-nm hello.elf` might also tell you something helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your binary follows the Arm ELF specification there is an attribute section that contains information on the cpu architecture and (if applicable) the architecture profile. This information can be extracted by readelf. Note that the information is the compiler and linkers view of things and can sometimes be wrong.

The first example below is from a binary built for Cortex-A8 and the second example is a binary built for Cortex-M33. Both are built using the IAR toolchain.

```
> readelf -A cortex-a8.out                                                       
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_conformance: "2.10"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_PCS_config: Bare platform
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: small
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: compatible
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed

 > readelf -A cortex-m33.out
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_conformance: "2.10"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v8-M.mainline
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Microcontroller
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_FP_arch: FPv5/FP-D16 for ARMv8
  Tag_PCS_config: Bare platform
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: forced to int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP only
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: compatible
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. However, this `-A` argument only works for those bare-mental applications. For the multi-world projects on Cortex-M that are compiled into two executables (e.g, `FreeRTOSDemo_s.axf`, and `FreeRTOSDemo_ns.axf`), this argument does not give any output. Any suggestions on this? Thanks.

Comment: @AndyMa This method requires that the .ARM.attributes section is present in the elf file. If this section is missing you are out off luck since there are no fundamental differences between an elf-file for Cortex-A and Cortex-M.